# Getting values from single Firebase Firestore Document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is definitely a newbie question, and in part answered in the Firebase documentation, but for the life of me it's not working when implementing it in my own code - so I'm hoping the community can help me understand what I am doing wrong, and how to fix it.

When getting documents from Firestore, I can't access the actual values within, due to its structure, so when setting e.g. "var name = doc.name" it just gives me undefined. For getting MULTIPLE documents, I've already found apiece of code that works:

```
// Getting the document    
docRef.collection(collectionRef).get()
    .then((snapshots) => cleanData(snapshots))
    .then((items) => items.map((item) => sampleFunction(item)));

// Firebase Utility cleaning documents (array)
function cleanData(snapshots) {
    let data = [];
    snapshots.forEach(function(doc) {
        data.push({
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data()
        });
    });
    return data;
}
```

But when using this piece of code with e.g. collection("x").doc("id"), then it throws the error:
"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: snapshots.forEach is not a function"

So I went ahead to modify the function as follows:

```
// Firebase Utility cleaning document (single)
function cleanDoc(snap) {
    let data = [];
    data.push({
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data()
    });
    return data;
}
```

But that gives me "undefined" when attempting to access the values in my function again...

The documentation (in the city example) says to define a class. When I did that, I was able to get values from one document, but it gave me undefined the second time I called the same function on one page.

For context, I'm trying to display a User Profile, which displays people they work with on a project, which means I call these profiles as well, the data structure just callsa reference to the "worked with" profiles, and I get their ID's just fine, but when attempting to render an HTML item for each, the values within their profiles are undefined....Its confusing the hell out of me anyways.

Answer (score 1):

If your function is an async function:

```
collectionSnap = await docRef.collection(collectionRef).get();
val items=[]
await Promise.all(querySnap.docs.map(async (doc) => {
                // Do your your work and populate items
        }));
// Do your work with items
```

You can try this approach to processing your documents.

Comment: I've come across "await" a few times when looking at other problems with the asyncronicity. But when I use await, things don't build -.- 

I'm using Gulp & Babel to build my templates && compile the JS

Comment: If you can't use async/await, things get tricky. Most of the calls on firebase are asynchronous in nature, they mostly return promises which need to be resolved. Can you research a bit about Gulp & Babel to see why they don't build?